# Web API Server Sent Events not working properly

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-web-api, server-sent-events

I am currently working on a web site, which should also involve push notifications. I want to use server sent events, because I do not need to send an answer for my event back from the client to the server and therefore websockets are not required

The backend is a C# Web Api service and the code is based on this [tutorial](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/discussions/359056)

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Get(HttpRequestMessage request)
{
    HttpResponseMessage response = request.CreateResponse();
    Action<Stream, HttpContent, TransportContext> onStreamAvailable = delegate(Stream stream, HttpContent headers, TransportContext context)
    {
        if (stream != null)
        {
            StreamWriter outStream = new StreamWriter(stream);

            outStream.WriteLine("event: testEvent");
            outStream.WriteLine("data: hello world1!");
            outStream.WriteLine("");
            outStream.Flush();

            outStream.WriteLine("event: testEvent");
            outStream.WriteLine("data: hello world Nr. 2!");
            outStream.WriteLine("");
            outStream.Flush();

            outStream.WriteLine("event: testEvent");
            outStream.WriteLine("data: hello world Nr. 3!");
            outStream.WriteLine("");
            outStream.Flush();

            outStream.WriteLine("event: testEvent");
            outStream.WriteLine("data: hello world Nr. 4!");
            outStream.WriteLine("");
            outStream.Flush();

            outStream.WriteLine("event: testEvent");
            outStream.WriteLine("data: hello world Nr. 5!");
            outStream.WriteLine("");
            outStream.Flush();

        }

    };


    response.Content = new PushStreamContent(onStreamAvailable, "text/event-stream");
    return response;
}
```

When using this code, the browser showed the first four messages, but not the last one. I then started debug mode and found out, that the browser shows the first event, right after the second one is flushed and so forth.

I then made a telnet request to have a look at the output and this was the result:

[image: telnet result]

here I noticed that before every event there seems to be some text (maybe a byte encoded hexadecimal) which I didn't send. I thought maybe this is what the browser has trouble with.

Any idea what i can do to remove this? Or is the error something else?

Here is the JavaScript code for the browser:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var serverSentEvents = new window.EventSource('http://localhost:1278/api/subscribe');
        serverSentEvents.onmessage = function (e) {
            $("#messages").append(e.data + '<br />');
        };

        serverSentEvents.addEventListener("testEvent", function (e) {
            $("#messages").append(e.data + '<br />');
        });

        serverSentEvents.onerror = function (e) {
            alert('error');
        };
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I had a very similar problem in the past; it was due to the encoding. Maybe it helps to specify the text encoding as being ASCII or UTF8.

Comment: i tried UTF8, Unicode and ASCII like so: new StreamWriter(stream, Encoding.ASCII); none of them changed anything

Comment: Hmmm interesting. `29` = `)` and `2E` = `.`. Apparently, there is already written something to the stream. But I can't see where this is happening.

Comment: I think 29 and 2E are buffer lengths.